# Why are there so many certificates in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

[image: diagram of connections between components in a k8s cluster]

One Kubernetes cluster contains several components, for example, kubelet, etcd, api-server, etc.

We need to set up many certificates and keys when setting up a cluster, then they can carry these certificates to communicate with each other.

```
> kubectl describe pod kube-apiserver-controlplane -n=kube-system


Name:                 kube-apiserver-controlplane
Namespace:            kube-system
...
Controlled By:  Node/controlplane
Containers:
  kube-apiserver:
    Container ID:  docker://6974d026de0b2fadb3d2628d0df971ddc4c3d772665b2cd960a1d0e385f97a5d
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.20.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver@sha256:8b8125d7a6e4225b08f04f65ca947b27d0cc86380bf09fab890cc80408230114
    Command:
      kube-apiserver
      ...
      --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
      --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
      --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
      --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
      --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
      --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
      --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
      --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
      --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
      --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
      ...
      ...
```

I know the concept of Certificate Authority(CA), Certificate, mTLS, and the mechanism of HTTPs.

I know the zero-trust model.

**But I don't understand what security risk these Kubernetes certificates try to solve.**

If the hacker can get root access to our node, they can view everything including the certificate, this complexity seems not to give us more security.

### Questions

- What security risks are the most important (common) for a Kubernetes cluster?
- If I don't use certificates to protect internal communication within a cluster, how will the hacker attack me?

  As far as I know, the communication between AWS load balancer and EC2 is HTTP instead of HTTPs, it seems fine. Why are certificates not required between the load balancer and EC2, but required within a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: **If the hacker can get root access to our node,** -- it's a more significant concern.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to answer your multiple questions from my view:

> But I don't understand what problem these Kubernetes certificates try to solve.

1. According to [Zero trust security model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_trust_security_model), the main concept behind the zero trust security model is "**never trust, always verify**”.

   Kubernetes expects that all API communication in the cluster is encrypted by default with TLS, which always checks the **identity and integrity** of communication between different components.

   One common scenario is referred to as a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

> What security risks are the most important (common) for a Kubernetes
> cluster?

2. I think the most important security emphysis for a Kubernetes cluster are `tls for all traffic`/`Authentication`/`Authorization`.

   You could also refer to the official docs: [securing your cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/securing-a-cluster)

> If I don't use certificates to protect internal communication within a cluster, how will you attract me?

3. Better not do that.

> Why are certificates not required between the load balancer and EC2, but required within a Kubernetes cluster?

4. That's two different concepts.

   AWS load balancer and EC2 are infrastructure-layer(Iaas) components, which are only responsible for transmitting data stream. You can enforce security options on your own.

   On the other hand, components within a Kubernetes cluster are application-layer ones, which should include secure in-cluster communication by default.